Remove URL and keep file name with extension
I am having this type of urls in multiple excel cells:
https://stock-media-files.co/previews/e-C-10071-z-a/filename.jpg

Of course the address is always different so REPLACE cannot be used
I want to keep only filename.jpg in every cell
Assuming that my url in at cell A1 tried with this formula:
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))-1),"\",REPT(" ",255)),255))

But throws error. Not working.
I am using Excel LTSC PRO 2021
Any help please?

Office 365: =TEXTAFTER(A1,"/",-1)
Where -1 means first found from the right of the text value.
Older: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",255)),255))
This changes all / into a space character repeated 255 times. Next it returns the last 255 characters of the amended string. This is the characters after the last found /  and 255 minus the length of the string after the last /. TRIM removes al leading space characters, which leaves the string only.

Since your local settings have a , for decimal separator, your Excel can't use , as a delimiter for it's arguments. Therefor it uses ; (and likely \ for vertical array separator: ={1\2\3})

I am using Excel LTSC PRO 2021. Both formulas you wrote throw same error as my formula. Not working

What error, since at least the last should work

Error is: There's a problem with this formula. Just this. To both

Do you have a different delimiter, for instance: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";REPT(" ";255));255))?

OMG. This worked! Please explain why and edit your answer. Thank you!

Added an explanation to the suggested answers + the difference in delimiters.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@P.b, =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))) would work too, right?

@nkalvi correct, and if the end string could be bigger than 255 characters, that would be advisable. I took 255 from his own attempt
